# WPF dialog loaded event and MsgBox location

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, msgbox

I'm opening a MsgBox in the Loaded event of a dialog using `Dispatcher.Invoke()` method
(If a condition is met the msgbox is displayed and the dialog will not be shown 
 - after clicking ok on the msgbox).
But I noticed the msgbox is not displayed at the same location as other msgboxes opened not in the loaded event.
For some reasons..I would like it to be at the same location.
Anyone knows why it happens and how to fix it? (I don't want the diloag to be shown if the msgbox is shown because it points out to an error)

Thank you!

EDIT:
The expected location of the MessageBox is at the center and the actual MessageBox is at the center with some offset down - not a big offset but something I noticed
CORRECTION: the MsgBox is a Window that serves as a MessageBox

Comment: MsgBox is a VB function, in WPF you should be using the one called MessageBox. Although it doesn’t bring much confusion, it is alway a good practice to use the right terms.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more what is the expected and what is the actual location of the message box?

Comment: What is the WindowStartupLocation of your MsgBox window? If it is CenterOwner, what is the Owner?

Comment: WindowStartupLocation =CenterScreen